# How to shut down computer with PowerShell?

Tags: powershell

I would like to do shutdown process in my script.
I use `Stop-Computer`. But it always reboots, doesn't shut down. I tried `stop-computer` alone, it works, but when I applied it to my script, it reboots, doesn't shut down, can anyone give any idea please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to shut down computer on `Workgroup environment`.

Scenario: You want to shut down computer named HP-ZBook from your computer named PC1

**Step-1**:On PC1 => Start Powershell in `admin mode`

**Step-2**:On PC1 => Run command to check if HP-ZBOOK is in trusted host
list of PC1

```
Get-Item WSMan:\localhost\Client\TrustedHosts
```

**Step-3**:On PC1 Run command to add HP-ZBOOK to trusted host list of
PC1

```
Set-Item WSMan:\localhost\Client\TrustedHosts -Value 'HP-ZBOOK'
```

[image]

**Step-4**:On HP-ZBOOK => Start powershell in `admin mode`

**Step-5**:On HP-ZBOOK run below command to start WinSRM service and Enable WinRM firewall Exception

```
WinRM QuickConfig
```

[image]

**Step-6**:On PC1 Run command to shutdown computer HP-ZBOOK

```
   Stop-Computer -ComputerName HP-ZBook -force
```

[image]

Answer (score 7):

Refer to [stop-computer](https://ss64.com/ps/stop-computer.html), you can use `-Force` to force an immediate shut down of the computer.

---

```
stop-computer -computername localhost -Force
```

Comment: There is no need for `-computername localhost`, it's the default behavior, as explained in your own link

Answer (score 2):

The Stop-Computer cmd lets you shuts down the local computer and remote computers(if any)

You can use the parameters of Stop-Computer to specify the authentication levels and alternate credentials, and to force an immediate shut down.

**to shut down your local machine -**

```
Stop-Computer -ComputerName localhost
```

-ComputerName
Specifies the computers to stop. The default is the local computer.

Answer (score 2):

Using `shutdown.exe:

```
shutdown.exe /s /f
```

Answer (score 1):

Not found any option like reason code in cmdlet

Similar like
Shutdown /s /f /d P:0:0

Stop-computer